# create FTP user in Plesk control panel via PHP

Tags: php, ftp, plesk

is it possible to do that? I've seen the commandline instructions but it seems that passwd is an interactive command and we can't respond via PHP.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `popen` and `chpasswd`.

```
$handle = popen('/usr/sbin/chpasswd', 'w');
fputs($handle, "user:password");
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try to emulating human with CURL.
Login + Create Account. Simple example with one form http://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2004-04/0013.html